# Java TreeSet sorting

Tags: java

I found this question from a book but it was hard to figure out the way behind the answer.

```
     public class Drink implements Comparable{

            public String name ;
            public int compareTo(Object o){
            return 0;
            }

        }
```

and:

```
    Drink one=new Drink();
    Drink two=new Drink();
    one.name="Coffee";
    two.name="Tea";
    TreeSet set=new TreeSet();
    set.add(one);
    set.add(two);
```

If a programmer iterates over the TreeSet and prints the name of each Drink object, what is the result?

Could someone please help me to get the answer by describing the way behind it.

Comment: Stop being lazy. Just debug it. If all else fails, take a look at how Comparable works and what returning 0 does.

Comment: Can you please iterate and let us know ?

Comment: In this case you are literally just calling `return 0` so each element will be thought that it is equal to the other so nothing will change

Comment: Guys, since this is an edge case, there is a point in the question. Testing it might prove nothing if this case is not defined, and to answer if it is - one must consult the documentation. (In this case however, the result is perfectly defined)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only "Coffee" (`one`) is added to the set, since the TreeSet returns equality according to the `compareTo()`, and since the element is already in the set, noting will happen when you try to add `two`.

From the java docs:

[TreeSet:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit
>   comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals if it is to
>   correctly implement the Set interface. (See Comparable or Comparator
>   for a precise definition of consistent with equals.) This is so
>   because the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation,
>   but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its
>   compareTo (or compare) method, so two elements that are deemed equal
>   by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The
>   behavior of a set is well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent
>   with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the Set
>   interface.

[add():](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add(E))

> ...
>   If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
>   unchanged and returns false.

---

Also note, that this is unadvised behavior that do not follow the `Set` interface contract, since you did not override `equals()`.